# Integrating a traditional Core Data stack with iCloud: Conflict management

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm developing an iOS application, and I've hit a brick wall with conflict management in Core Data. So far, I've built a Core Data stack, whose entities sync with iCloud, without much trouble.

But conflict management remains an enormous problem.

1. Apple's UIManagedDocument exposes a public interface that's been designed to make it easy for developers to handle document-version conflicts. In my application, the documents (NSManagedObjects in my Core Data stack) need to have relationships with other NSManagedObjects--as far as I can tell, that means I need to use a traditional Core Data stack, rather than UIManagedDocument. Is that true?
2. As far as I can tell, the only way to handle conflict management in a "normal" Core Data stack is to subclass NSMergePolicy. Is that correct?
3. If the answers to (1) and (2) are YES, then I need to subclass NSMergePolicy so that:

*If the user edits document A on both device X and device Y while iCloud is unavailable (e.g. because the devices are both in Airplane mode), then the NSMergePolicy subclass needs to save both of these versions of document A to the iCloud store. This is how Apple's Notes app works.*

Unfortunately, I've found almost no information on how to properly subclass NSMergePolicy for such a task. Apple's documentation has very little to say on the topic. Could you explain how one might approach the task, or direct me toward an in-depth tutorial/sample project?

4. Is there a better/easier/simpler way than subclassing NSMergePolicy?

I really appreciate your help. I'm hesitant to try anything before I'm sure what the right approach would be.

Thanks,
Robert